# How to list the linux partitions by their created/modified time?

Tags: linux, partitioning

Is there any command to list the linux partitions by their created/modified time.

Comment: I've heard of timestamps of files, but I haven't heard of timestamps on partitions themselves.  If you're the only administrator of the machine, you can do some detective work looking at shell history to determine when fdisk or similar commands were run.

Answer (score 1):

Neither [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) not [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) stores such information for partitions. Some filesystems may, but this applies to the filesystem itself, not a partition. For the ext family the command

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sdx1
```

will print (among other things) something like:

```
Filesystem created:       Mon Apr  4 16:08:44 2016
Last mount time:          Mon Oct  1 12:48:51 2018
Last write time:          Mon Oct  1 12:48:51 2018
```